# Adaptar CSS a QtDesigner para python

Tags: python, qt-designer

quiero poner un botón en QtDesigner con un estilo que vi en internet pero la nomenclatura cambia y no se como adaptarla. ¿ alguien me puede ayudar ?, adjunto el código de internet:

```
    /* From uiverse.io */
button {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
}

button.learn-more {
 width: 12rem;
 height: auto;
}

button.learn-more .circle {
 transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 width: 3rem;
 height: 3rem;
 background: #282936;
 border-radius: 1.625rem;
}

button.learn-more .circle .icon {
 transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 background: #fff;
}
```

Y el código de QtDesigner empieza con pushButton y al cambiarlo en el código anterior no pasa nada.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no es posible ya que qt no usa css sino una variable qss.

Comment: Hola Loselio, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, se que es frustrante no tener acceso a los comentarios, solo te puedo decir que tengas paciencia, apenas sumes unos puntos, vas a poder acceder a ellos y también al chat.